# Implement IEnumerable, but avoid 'MyClass' does not implement interface member 'IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'

Tags: c#, .net, interface, ienumerable

I have a custom class that, at it's core, is a list of float's. Elsewhere in the app, I'd like to loop through it with a ForEach, so on the class definition, I'm trying to just implement IEnumerable.  But when I do that, I am told that:

```
'MyClass' does not implement interface member 'IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'
```

I understand the error.  I'm just wondering if there is a way around it, other than actually implementing GetEnumerator in MyClass.

Comment: Instead of implementing `IEnumerable`, can you use `List<T>`? This would give you all the meat, and only override what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's difficult to advise.

Comment: `ForEach` ? - if it is custom method of your class why do you need to implement anything else? Note that if you *only* need to use `foreach` you don't need to actually implement `IEnumerable` (still need functional `GetEnumerator()` so)

Comment: So if I understand, you want to implement an interface without implementing it? No you can't do that.

Comment: You probably want to implement it by just calling the .GetEnumerator from the list field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid manually implementing IEnumerable, the language supports some syntactic sugar that auto-generates most of it for you. It's not implementing `IEnumerable<>` on your class (if you want it, you've got to implement it, as other people have said), but it's close.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private bool TryGetNextFloat(out float nextFloat) {/* Whatever */};
    public IEnumerable<float> AsEnumerable()
    { 
        float nextFloat = 0;
        while(this.TryGetNextFloat(out nextFloat))
        {
            yield nextFloat;
        }
    }
}

// Elsewhere
foreach (var f in myClassInstance.AsEnumerable())
{
    // Do something with f
}
```

(Note that if you have a literal enumerable of floats in your class, this is a trivial problem and you could simply return that as an IEnumerable.)

Comment: You could just `return data` as the implementation of `AsEnumerable` instead, and it'd be simpler, faster, easier, clearer, etc.

Comment: Obviously, that solution is trivial. I'm assuming that the statement "at it's core, is a list of float's" =/=> "has a literal list of floats". Updated the code sample a bit.